# vue2 reactive filter values?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, vuejs2

I can't get my computed filter values to update when the vm data updates. In my case, I have some moment datetimes stored on the VM model in UTC. Then I have a filter which displays those times formatted to a timezone using moment. Then I want to have a toggle to switched the timezone if the user wants, but when they switch the timezone, the filter values do not update accordingly. Am I missing something to make them reactive? Additionally, it's not even using my default value of `selectedTz: 'America\Los_Angeles'` (you'll notice it starts off showing all the times as TZ +0 (UTC) despite this default setting).

```js
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            games: [{start_time: '2017-01-23 21:00:00'}, {start_time: '2017-01-23 22:00:00'}, {start_time: '2017-01-23 23:00:00'}],
            selectedTz: 'America/Los_Angeles'
        },
        methods: {
            switchToEast: function () {
                this.selectedTz = 'America/New_York'
            },
            switchToWest: function () {
                this.selectedTz = 'America/Los_Angeles'
            }
        },
        filters: {
            usertz: function (date) {
                var tz = this.selectedTz
                var x = new moment.tz(date, 'Etc/UTC')
                x.tz(tz)
                return x.format('MMM Do @ h:mm a Z')
            }
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <p class="text-right">All times are in {{ selectedTz }}</p>
    <div class="text-right">
        <button class="button" @click="switchToEast()">East</button>
        <button class="button" @click="switchToWest()">West</button>
    </div>
    <p v-for="game in games">
        {{ game.start_time | usertz }}
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a problem like this with filters, too. Couldn't solve it with filters and decided to do it with computed properties. In my opinion, filters can't handle much computing. The documentation itself says

> filters are primarily designed for text transformation purposes

Try it like I this and it should work.

```js
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            games: [{start_time: '2017-01-23 21:00:00'}, {start_time: '2017-01-23 22:00:00'}, {start_time: '2017-01-23 23:00:00'}],
            selectedTz: 'America/Los_Angeles'
        },
        methods: {
            switchToEast: function () {
                Vue.set(this, 'selectedTz', 'America/New_York')
            },
            switchToWest: function () {
                Vue.set(this, 'selectedTz', 'America/Los_Angeles')
            }
        },
        computed: {
            filteredGames: function () {
                var filteredList = []
                for (i = 0; i < this.games.length; i++) { 
                    var x = new moment.tz(this.games[i].start_time, 'Etc/UTC')
                    x.tz(this.selectedTz)
                    filteredList.push({start_time: x.format('MMM Do @ h:mm a Z')})
                }
                return filteredList
            }
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <p class="text-right">All times are in {{ selectedTz }}</p>
    <div class="text-right">
        <button class="button" @click="switchToEast()">East</button>
        <button class="button" @click="switchToWest()">West</button>
    </div>
    <p v-for="game in filteredGames">
        {{ game.start_time }}
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I considered this approach but it seemed 'less elegant' but I guess if the filters won't work that way I'll have to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with you. Being able to use a filter here would be much cooler in my opinion, too. Nevertheless, I don't think it will work. If you do a console.log in your filter on tz, you'll see that it's undefined. It's a shame because I'd love to do more with filters.

Comment: It's more elegant with the filter, and you can use it... but to the only thing it is pertinent, that is the format... not change the TimeZone, that is more pertnent as a computed property...

Answer (score 2):

While the answer that was marked as correct runs... it delegates to the computer attributes the job to transform date AND format for presentation. While format should be the work of the filter.

Change the timezone reacting to a the chosen attribute, is really the job of computed property. But you could let the computed property transform all the dates to a Moment.js object, and use the filter only to format the rendering of the date... that is the exact job of the filter.

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        games: [{start_time: '2017-01-23 21:00:00'}, {start_time: '2017-01-23 22:00:00'}, {start_time: '2017-01-23 23:00:00'}],
        selectedTz: 'America/Los_Angeles'
    },
    methods: {
        switchToEast: function () {
            Vue.set(this, 'selectedTz', 'America/New_York')
        },
        switchToWest: function () {
            Vue.set(this, 'selectedTz', 'America/Los_Angeles')
        }
    },
    computed: {
        filteredGames: function () {
            var filteredList = []
            for (var game of this.games) {
                var start_time = new moment.tz(game.start_time, 'Etc/UTC')
                start_time.tz(this.selectedTz)

                game.start_time = start_time
                filteredList.push(game)
            }

            return filteredList
        }
    },
    filters: {
        datetime: function(date) {
            return date.format('MMM Do @ h:mm a Z')
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <p class="text-right">All times are in {{ selectedTz }}</p>
    <div class="text-right">
        <button class="button" @click="switchToEast()">East</button>
        <button class="button" @click="switchToWest()">West</button>
    </div>
    <p v-for="game in filteredGames">
        {{ game.start_time | datetime }}
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: that's a good solution too, after thinking about it more yesterday I totally agree with your statements

Answer (score 0):

Filters can take additional parameters. If you move all reactive variable from the function body to the parameters it should work. For example:

```vue
<template>
  {{ message | filter(data) }}
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    filters: {
      filter(message, data) {
        return `Message: ${message}, Data: ${data}`;
      },
    },

    data() {
      return {
        data: "Try changing me!",
      };
    },

    props: {
      message: String,
    },
  };
</script>
```

Or in your example:

```js
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            games: [{start_time: '2017-01-23 21:00:00'}, {start_time: '2017-01-23 22:00:00'}, {start_time: '2017-01-23 23:00:00'}],
            selectedTz: 'America/Los_Angeles'
        },
        methods: {
            switchToEast: function () {
                this.selectedTz = 'America/New_York'
            },
            switchToWest: function () {
                this.selectedTz = 'America/Los_Angeles'
            }
        },
        filters: {
            usertz: function (date, tz) {
                var x = new moment.tz(date, 'Etc/UTC')
                x.tz(tz)
                return x.format('MMM Do @ h:mm a Z')
            }
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <p class="text-right">All times are in {{ selectedTz }}</p>
    <div class="text-right">
        <button class="button" @click="switchToEast()">East</button>
        <button class="button" @click="switchToWest()">West</button>
    </div>
    <p v-for="game in games">
        {{ game.start_time | usertz(selectedTz) }}
    </p>
</div>
```